# Why is my comparison program not working?

Tags: python

Hey I'm reviewing for an exam I have on Tuesday for a Python class and I'm trying to make a program that checks 2 lists to see if they both have the same items/values, just in different order.

This is what I have so far:

```
def reOrder(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False
    for element1 in list1:
        foundElement = False
        for element2 in list2:
            if element1 == element2:
                foundElement = True
        if foundElement == False:
            return False
        else:
            return True


print(reOrder([1,7,10,8,4,2], [3,1,8,10,2,4]))
```

For some reason it still prints True on the above statement. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't return true until you have checked all elements of list1

Comment: You will uncoditionally return `True` or `False` in the very first iteration of the outer loop. Take some time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code, as that would make it even more obvious than it is by simply reading the code.

Comment: well thats because it returns on the first value `1` itself the function does not complete remove the return True and paste it at last

Comment: I second the advice of stepping through your code in a debugger. You could use Visual Studio Code with the Python plugin, or other options depending on your operating system.

Comment: `def reOrder(l1, l2):
    return sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it In the OPs post we return the value `True` because in the list compares `1` in both the list and checks validates its  truth and `return True` it does not check the next value `7` and so on  and the function does not continue to execute the rest of the list element because of the `return True` statement so removing that and placing at the end of the two loops will ensure that the after checking all the conditions the `True` case is returned as the result

```
def reOrder(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False
    for element1 in list1:
        foundElement = False
        for element2 in list2:
            if element1 ==element2:
                foundElement=True
        if foundElement ==False:
            return False    
    return True
print(reOrder([1,3,10,8,4,2], [3,1,8,10,2,4]))
```

OUTPUT

```
False
```

i would prefer sorting the two lists and then checking the corresponding element as the complexity would reduce to O(n*logn) as this code is clearly o(n2)

Comment: I can't see what functionality you've changed from the original and you've provided no explanation regarding the change you made.

Comment: im sorry for the above pls check again

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that if the two lists have the same elements then every elements of the second list should be in the first list and vice versa. Meaning if even one element in list2 is not in list1 then the two lists are not the same.

```
def reOrder(list1,list2):
Found = False
if len(list1)!=len(list2):
    return False
for e in list2:
    if e not in list1:
        return False
return True     
print(reOrder([1,7,10,8,4,2], [3,1,8,10,2,4]))
```